# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't suspend properly and doesn't start

Tags: suspend

When I suspend it, display goes off but the fans in the case are still working and the case  lights don't blink slowly(like they normally do when the pc suspends), in short it didn't fully suspend however for example my g15 keyboard lights are off. Now, when i press any key to wake it the keyboard lights goes on but the lcd app doesn't start and obviously their is no display in the monitor.

My graphics card is : HD  Radeon 5770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu is not installed with suspend because it is known to cause problems. To test suspend open a terminal and type: 'sudo pm-suspend' or  'sudo pm-hibernate"

If you want to run suspend frequently i would recommend you install the power management tool by typing "sudo apt-get install powermanagement-interface'

Then these terminal codes will also be handy

'pmi action suspend' and  "pmi action hibernate'

Comment: sudo pm-suspend worked. Suspend works also but not all the time that is. Sometimes if I am opening alot of stuff it wouldn't suspend probably.
So should i install this power management tool you mentioned to avoid this?

Comment: It definitely helps.